Minimal perfect hash function that retains mapping of existing keys on expansion
I have a set of N integers in the range 0 to 255 which must be mapped using a minimally perfect hash function to the range [0, N-1]. However, this set of integers can grow dynamically. In the case where the set grows, is there a way to implement a minimal perfect hash function that retains the mapping of the existing elements when new elements are added to a set?
For e.g. consider this mapping:
11 -> 0
27 -> 1

When a new element 17 is added, I want it to be mapped to index 2 so that the new mapping is like this:
11 -> 0
27 -> 1
17 -> 2

This is because I want to avoid having to rehash all the elements when my set of integers expand. Is this theoretically possible?

This is probably better suited at https://cs.stackoverflow.com or https://math.stackoverflow.com

Can we use like this? 1. create an empty list 2. Everytime you get a new element you add it to the list and index of that element becomes its hash. I think it fulfils all your requirement. Infact I will dare and post it as an answer

Mathematically speaking Anubhav’s solution is the only possible way to do this. Consider that the elements can be added in any order: therefore, your mapping function needs to somehow store enough information to reconstruct an arbitrary insertion ordering. That is by definition a list of the elements by insertion order. There won’t be a simpler solution.

Dynamic perfect hashing won't do it?

Consider the hashing algorithm which is defined as:
list = [];
hash(x){
    if(x not in list){
        list.add(x);
    }
    return list.indexOf(x);
};

Since all your numbers are in range [0,255], number of elements in list will never go beyond 256. Even if you increase the range, it works as long as your range is finite.
Also, indexOf operation preserves the previous hash values and ensures one to one mapping for value-hash pair.

This is basically as good as it gets. For an actual implementation you’ll probably want to maintain a dictionary/hash table of mappings for efficiency (rather than scanning the entire list each time).

yes, but I am struggling to digest that I need to implement one more hash to generate this hash. It becomes layered and so more prone to any oversights. I will think over it and perhaps update my answer tomorrow.

A slight update to Anubhav's solution which is a bit more performant (Python syntax, using the dict hashmap type):
phf = {}
def phf_hash(k):
    """
    Hash a key with the perfect hashing function.
    Expand the PHF if the key has not been seen yet.
    """
    if k not in phf:
        phf[k] = len(phf)
    return phf[k]

Example usage:
>>> phf_hash(11)
0
>>> phf_hash(27)
1
>>> phf_hash(17)
2
>>> phf_hash(27)
1
>>> phf_hash(11)
0

